# Cross Button does not work on the settings page when I set my app to show the onboarding screen again. iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

I have created a crossbutton in the navigation bar to exit from the settings page. It works fine all the times except when i reset the app to show the onboarding screen again, the app works fine but i can't close the settings view with the corss button however i can still swipe down to dismiss it on iphone and ipad.

Please ignore my english as its not my first language.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
```

Environment declaration

```
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
  @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding : Bool = false
```

Body

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false)   {
                VStack (spacing : 20){
                    //MARK: - Section 1
                    GroupBox( 
                        label :
                            SettingsLabelView(labelText: "Fructus", labelImage: "info.circle")
                    ){
                        Divider().padding(.vertical,4)
                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10, content: {
                            Image("logo")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .leading)
                                .cornerRadius(9)
                            Text("Most fruits are naturally low in fat, sodium and calories. None have cholestrol. Fruits are sources of many essentials nutrients including potassium, dietary fiber, vitamins and more.")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        })  
                        }
```

Reset button Implementation

```
                    //MARK: - Section 2
                    GroupBox(label : SettingsLabelView(labelText: "Customization", labelImage: "paintbrush"))
                    {
                        Divider().padding(.vertical,10)
                        Text("If you wish you can restart the application by tooggling the switch in this box. That way the onboarding process starts again and you will be able to see the onboarding screen again.")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .padding(.vertical,8)
                            .frame(minHeight : 60)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .layoutPriority(1)
                        Toggle(isOn : $isOnboarding){
                            if isOnboarding {
                                Text("Restarted".uppercased())
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                            } else {
                                Text("Reset".uppercased())
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemBackground)
                              .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8,style: .continuous)))
                   
                    }
```

Next Group Box

```
           GroupBox(label : SettingsLabelView(labelText: "Application", labelImage: "apps.iphone"))
                    {
                        
                        SettingsRowView(name: "Developer & Designer", content: "Satya Prakash Sahu")
                        SettingsRowView(name: "Freamework", linkLabel: "SwiftUI 2.0", linkDestination: "developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/")
                        SettingsRowView(name: "Version", content: "1.1.0")
                        }
```

Cross Button Declaration and implementation

```
 .navigationBarTitle("Settings",displayMode: .large)
                .padding()
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                            Button(action: {
                                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            })
                )
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Preview
struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre] that we can run?